# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una JProgressBar?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo una JProgressBar y me sale en color anaranjado, he intentado cambiar el color con esto pero no ha dado resultados:

```
 UIManager.put("progresoIP.background", Color.BLUE);
 UIManager.put("progresoIP.foreground", Color.BLUE);
 UIManager.put("progresoIP.selectionBackground", Color.BLUE);
 UIManager.put("progresoIP.selectionForeground", Color.BLUE);
```

y con esto:

```
  progresoIP.setForeground(Color.blue);
  progresoIP.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

Posicionados bajo `initComponents();`

sigue igual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una buena aproximación, si no escribes tu propio `painter`, es haciendo uso de `nimbusOrange`, lo cual hace posible la sobre-escritura de las propiedades de todos los componentes Swing bajo el LAF Nimbus; Es una solución, a mi modo de ver, bastante rápida.

***Abajo un pequeño snippet*:**

```
UIManager.put( "nimbusOrange", new Color( 38, 139, 210 ) );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Johnny, ¿podrías elaborar un poco mas tu respuesta? El sistema la marcó de baja calidad por su pobre contenido. Tal vez podrías explicar como funciona tu código o algo asi.

Comment: Listo toledano, respuesta ampliada; Te agradezco muchísimo tu aviso y sugerencia.

Comment: Muchas gracias, habia intentado un painter pero no me dio resultado deseado, este me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score -1):

Este código que esta `void main()` quitalo

Este código quitalo:

```
try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HullTestGUI2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HullTestGUI2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HullTestGUI2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HullTestGUI2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Con esto se pone por el `LookandFeel` por default de Windows y ya con esto podras cambiarlo con las instrucciones de:

```
    jProgressBar.setBackground(Color.elquequieras);
    jProgressBar.setForeground(Color.elquequieras);
```

Y con esto jala.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución Abad, desafortunadamente se reporto como "muy baja calidad", considera agregar una explicación de lo que realiza el código o en que ayudaría a responder la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos.